# Extract Pdf from MySql Dump Saved as Text

Tags: mysql, pdf, text, extract

I have a MySql database dump saved as a text file and am trying to find a way of extracting the indivdual pdf documents stored in one of the tables. All my research online so far has drawn a blank.

The data in the exported text file is in the following format:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `codocs`;

CREATE TABLE `codocs` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `COCODE` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `FILENAME` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `DATE` date NOT NULL,
  `USER` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `DOCUMENT` mediumblob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `oc` (`COCODE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

LOCK TABLES `codocs` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `codocs` DISABLE KEYS */;

INSERT INTO `codocs` (`ID`, `COCODE`, `FILENAME`, `DATE`, `USER`, `DOCUMENT`)
VALUES
    (1,’123456’,’document-2016-01-18.pdf','2016-01-21’,’user1’,X’8CB7638C2840B32D3AB66DDBB66DDBB66DDBB6BDC7B66DDBB6B1C7336F9F736EDECD4DBE1FE7477752D555ABBB562A59D5A40A2262B48C74CC0450A48747734B04508C040C04F64656 …
D2495CC3D8C1FCB8845D1D6F6C717E5EFB493B431B1250782FFFC12FD518D0E4EBF951D3B98F3C7971C1235F54B793172A427FF0F'),
    (2,’234567’,’document-2016-01-18.pdf','2016-01-22’,’user1’,X’8CF763702E4EF02D0AC7B6ED64C7B66DDB7E62DBB6EDECD8C98E6DDBB66D3B797FE79C5BEFAD5BF5FF70AA66BAAA7B7AD674AD999A5A4DAE282A4EC744CF4204437E7038BB4804C344C448646F6C4504C3CB4B04C3A0EAE900206210317231B2B137FFCF57343207381331FF9 …
971C1235F54B793172A427FF0F'),
    (3,’…
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Update: 20220112

I have since restored the database from the sql dump and have subsequently created the following php files to try to display the pdfs stored in the codocs table:

**db.php**  - contains the mysql database connection - *this is working*

**records_list.php**  - lists all the records in the codocs table including a button on each returned row to view the stored pdf - *this is working*

**view_pdf.php**  - receives the ID for the record clicked on from the records_list.php file and passes the selected record ID to the SELECT statement and displays the correct (*presumably, as different data is returned for each separate record clicked on in the records_list.php file*) raw mediumblob code stored in the database -
*this is not working as intended*

The following code is for the view_pdf.php file:

```
<?php
    $pdf_id = $_REQUEST['pdfID'];
    require_once "db.php";
    if(isset($pdf_id)) {
        $myID = $pdf_id;
        $sql = "select * from codocs where ID='" . $myID . "'";
        if (!$result=mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
        echo mysqli_error($con);
        } else {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            echo $row["DOCUMENT"];
            mysqli_close($con);
        }
    }
?>
```

As mentioned just the raw mediumblob data appears to be being returned.

If the following line is replaced:

```
            echo $row["DOCUMENT"];
```

with

```
            echo  '<object data="data:application/pdf;base64,'.base64_decode($row['DOCUMENT']).'" type="application/pdf" style="height:1000px;width:100%"></object>';
```

or

```
            echo base64_decode($row['DOCUMENT']);
```

it makes no difference. Raw code continues to be returned.
If the original line of code referred to above is replaced with

```
            header('Content-type: application/pdf'); 
            echo $row["DOCUMENT"];
```

a downloadable pdf is offered and can be saved but is unreadable with the following warning: "This PDF document might not be displayed correctly." and the following error: "Unable to open document file:///...document.pdf. File type unknown (application/octet-stream) is not supported."

Can anyone advise how the code above can be amended to allow the retrieval of the stored pdf files?

Is the X that precedes the single quotations marks shown surrounding the mediumblob data in the sql dump file of any significance?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Further Update 20220112:

The following are example unreadable pdf restores but generate 'pdf' files of differing sizes:

Record 554:

Using the following replacement code:

```
            header('Content-type: application/pdf'); 
            echo $row["DOCUMENT"];
```

generates an unreadable file 82.2Kb in size.

Using the following replacement code:

```
            header('Content-type: application/pdf'); 
            echo  '<object data="data:application/pdf;base64,'.base64_decode($row['DOCUMENT']).'" type="application/pdf" style="height:1000px;width:100%"></object>';
```

generates an unreadable file 15.6Kb in size.

Using the following replacement code:

```
            header('Content-type: application/pdf'); 
            echo  '<object data="data:application/pdf;base64,'.base64_encode($row['DOCUMENT']).'" type="application/pdf" style="height:1000px;width:100%"></object>';
```

generates an unreadable file 109.7Kb in size.

Any thoughts on helping to resolve the issue would be very welcome.

Comment: It will help us help you if you [edit] your question to show us the `CREATE TABLE codocs` statement from your dump file. The data type of your `DOCUMENT` column is probably `BLOB` (binary large object) but it would help to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, O.Jones. I've updated the code to include the information requested.